# Visual Studio 2005 and Sitecore ...Very very slow

Tags: visual-studio-2005, sitecore

We have Visual Studio 2005 and using Sitecore. In Sitecore solution we have different 4 projects. The problem is whenever I debug it takes much time to debug and then after debug when I run in browser it takes even more longer time.

I tried to clean the solution but did not work and I am trying to fix from many hours now and cannot find any solution.

I tired to create new project separately then it works fine its only with this solution of Sitecore which has problem.

Can anyone please help me...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

this is a common problem in all versions of Visual Studio which is due to the many files in the /sitecore folder WHEN you have the "Show all files" turned on, on the project which contains Sitecore. I think Visual Studio tries to load each and every file when debugging with that option turned on.

Turn it off and you should be good to go :)

Comment: HI..Thanks for answer 
Yesterday I tried many different things, edit the config files of framework added diff options...and restarted system many times, cleaned the project so It started working OK for now and I don't know what was the problem- But I know this happened before then work good for some time and then again slow. But I have turned off show all files also so will see if its keep working....

Thanks again...

Answer (score 2):

We include the Sitecore directory as a virtual directory in IIS, this way we don't have to have the Sitecore folder under the VS project root. Our typical setup for Sitecore is something like this:

```
/Site
 /Website
   /Layouts
   /XSL
   /Bin
   /...
 /Virtual
   /Sitecore
   /Sitecore Modules
   /Data
```

The Visual Studio project then looks at the /Site/Website folder and knows nothing about the virtual folder.